# How to synchronize textures animation and sound in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I'm creating a RPGGameKit using SpriteKit to help me develop my iOS games. Now that my player can move, I added animations and an audio system.

I ran on a problem to synchronize textures and sounds. Like a step when my player walk.

```
let atlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Walk")
let textures = atlas.getTextures() // I created an extension that returns textures of atlas

let walkingAnimation = SKAction.animate(with: textures, timePerFrame: 1)
```

So, `walkingAnimation` will loop through textures and change it every 1 second.

Now, I want to play a walking sound when the texture changes.

I have look at SKAction and SpriteKit documentation but there is no callback for this SKAction.

If you want to try to get this done with me or you have ideas of how to do it, please leave a comment.

Thanks :)

Comment: Something like the following will work -  let sequence = SKAction.sequence([walkinganimation,playsound]). Just to get the timing right.

Comment: I tried using group, sequence but the sound play once and the animation continue. I would like to be able to play a sound each time the frame changes.

Comment: How many frames do you have in your animation?

Comment: It depends on the animation but I want to abstract this part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for now I'm going to do it like this :

```
let textures = SKTextureAtlas(named: "LeftStep").getTextures()
var actions = [SKAction]()

for texture in textures {
    
    let group = SKAction.group([
        SKAction.setTexture(texture),
        SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Step.mp3", waitForCompletion: false)
    ])

    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([
        group,
        SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.5)
    ])

    actions.append(sequence)

}

self.node.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence(actions)))
```

Thanks @StefanOvomate

Comment: I will use this code until I find a better way to do it!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  let frame1 = SKAction.setTexture(yourTexture1)
  let frame2 = SKAction.setTexture(yourTexture2)
  let frame3 = SKAction.setTexture(yourTexture3)
  //etc

  let sound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("soundName", waitForCompletion: false)
  let oneSecond = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1)
  let sequence = SKAction.sequence([frame1,sound,oneSecond,frame2,sound,oneSecond,frame3,sound,oneSecond])

  node.run(sequence)
```

Comment: I don't want to have to specify each frames but I think I have to! I'll try and come back, thanks

Comment: I think the only other way is to find/create matching sound for your animation.

Answer (score 0):

I've found myself in the same situation, currently I'm doing the below. From what I have read in the documentation and seen online, the only way to do it is to create the audio file length to match one rotation of the texture animation.

```
        let walkAtlas = global.playerWalkAtlas
        var walkFrames: [SKTexture] = []
        
        let numImages = walkAtlas.textureNames.count
        for i in 1...numImages {
            let texture = "walk\(i)"
            walkFrames.append(walkAtlas.textureNamed(texture))
        }
        walking = walkFrames
        isWalking = true
        
        animateMove()
    }
 
    func animateMove(){
        let animateWalk = SKAction.animate(with: walking, timePerFrame: 0.05)
        let soundWalk = global.playSound(sound: .walkSound)
        
        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([soundWalk, animateWalk])
        
        self.run(SKAction.repeatForever(sequence),withKey: "isMoving")
    }
    
    func stopMoving(){
        self.removeAction(forKey: "isMoving")
        isWalking = false
    }
```

Comment: If you want to change the animation speed, you need to change the audio file length using a software like Audacity? 
Another problem I had is that I want to play a sound every 2 frames because a foot doesn't touch the ground at each frame on a walking animation